# How to get new rectangle value when x and y axis increase

Tags: math

I have a rectangle say (150, 200, 25,25) and x- axis up to 800 and y-axis upto 650. Now like to increase the value of x and y axis by 100. The rectangle value also increase according to x and y axis.

say my rectangle are in the shaded place. now i increase the x and y axis. the shaded position also increases. the rectangle value also need to increase so it placed in that shaded place as before.

How can i achieve this...

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Could you please add a before/after pair of images of your desired situation?

Comment: How to add images there is no option for that.
i got his one from one of frnd...
x,y(old)=800,650
x,y (new)=1600,1300
Rectangle(150,200,25,25)
ratio=newx/oldx
ratio1=newy/oldy
a =rectangle Width+(rectangle top - rectangle Width)/2
b=rectangle Height+(rectangle left  - rectangle Height)/2
rect top=(rectangle top- rectangle Width)*ratio
rect left=(rectangle left - rectangle Height)*ratio1
rect(new)=(a/ratio)+rect top/ratio,(b*ratio1)+(rect left/ratio1),(rect top*ratio)-(a*ratio),(b*ratio1)-(rect left/ratio1))
new rectangle will be (300,400,50,50)
The above works fine when double the x and y.

Comment: What will be the ratio if x and y increase by 100.

Answer (score 1):

ratio = Convert.ToDouble(new x- axis) / Convert.ToDouble(old x -axis);

rect1.X = Convert.ToInt16((rectangles[c].X) * ratio);
rect1.Y = Convert.ToInt16((rectangles[c].Y * ratio));
rect1.Width = Convert.ToInt16(rectangles[c].Width * ratio);
rect1.Height = Convert.ToInt16(rectangles[c].Height * ratio);

Answer (score 0):

Use a scale factor for each axis>

ScaleFactorX =  NewValueAxisX / OldValueAxisX  = 900/800 (in your example

NewRectValuesX = OldRectValuesX * ScaleFactorX

the same for Y axis

If your rect was at the top (at 800), now it will be at

NewRectValue = 800 * Scale = 800 * 900/800 = 800 (still at the top)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but my last line makes my quires wrong. so i deleted the lsat line.c  sorry for that..

say my rectangle are in the shaded place. now i increase the x and y axis. the shaded position also increases. the rectangle value also need to increase so it placed in that shaded place as before.